# RxSwift Events of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

When I implement `UITextFieldDelegate` through RxSwift, I do this:

```
self.textField_AddressType.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin).subscribe { _ in
    // Code here...
}.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

But when I apply it to `UITextView`,

```
self.textView.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin).subscribe { _ in
   // Code here...
}.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

I get an error:

> 'UITextView' is not a subtype of 'UIControl'

I couldn't find anything about this issue, is there another way to implement `UITextViewDelegate` in RxSwift?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
textView.rx.didBeginEditing.subscribe(onNext: { n in
  value = n
}, onCompleted: {
  completed = true
})
```

You can try this.

Comment: Hey, I don't really understand how this works? after I manage to subscribe where do I add the code? I am fairly new to IOS and RX and working on a small project filled with forms

Answer (score 4):

You can map event and create Observable string like this

```
self.tfUserName.rx.controlEvent(UIControlEvents.editingDidEnd)
        .map { self.tfUserName.text }
        .filter { $0 != nil }
        .map { $0! }
        .subscribe(onNext: { (text) in
            // Code here...
        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```